# Can i have a Vector of pointers in a Object *** p?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

So here's my question. I have a multidimessional array in wich i'm trying to put some objects deriven from class Block. I have this multidimessional array declared the following way:

```
Block ***arrTerrain;
```

where the first '*' is for the lines, the second '*' is for the collumns and the third is for the pointer to object inside the position (let's assume it's an object called FreeTerrain).

I initialize it this way:

```
this->arrTerrain = new Block**[a]; 

for(int i=0;i < a ;i++){
    arrTerrain[i] = new Block*[l];
}

for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<l;j++)
        arrTerrain[i][j] = new FreeTerrain;
```

I'm supposed to have soldiers in a given position (class soldier derives from block aswell). If i want to put 2 soldiers in the same position, i lose the pointer to the first one (obviusly). So i thought of having in each position a vector of Blocks or somesort but i find this difficult to implement.

Can anyone of you guys help me out?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Congratulations! You're a three-star programmer!

Comment: Are you masochist? If so, can you do an AMA?

Comment: If you're suggesting the use of a vector, why not use a vector from the start to represent this multidimensional array? Then again, you could become a **four-star** programmer and do `Block****`, but that's absurd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is yes, you can make a vector of (almost) anything.

Now the the implicit question is "SHOULD I make a vector of Object ***" and the answer is nooooooo.

First off, you should only use pointers when you have to. If you have an array of `FreeTerrain` that are all the same class, *don't* use new to them just make an array of `FreeTerrain`.

And you shouldn't hold an array in a vector, that's just asking for trouble.

Overall you should just use a `std::vector<std::vector<FreeTerrain>>`.

Edit: From the comments below, if you really need to use pointers (say, to have polymorphic references) use a unique pointer:

```
 std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<FreeTerrain>>> v;
```

Comment: I see what you're trying to say but my problem is: i got to have a 2D array. and if i just make a vector <FreeTerrain> i just blow the polymorphism. Because i need to have Soldiers or Castles.. FreeTerrain is just a representation of an empty space. 

Thanks for your answer though :)

Comment: @DiogoNunes Use a vector of [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or [`shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) then. A 2D array of these polymorphic objects could be `std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<FreeTerrain>>>`. You'd allocate them with [`std::make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique). If you use the shared pointers, then it's [`std::make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared).

Comment: Thank you for your time, you were very helpful. Cheers. And Mohammad too!